# how to integrate the Facebook with android application.?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

*Am successfully created the application in facebook and got the application ID*

```
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
```

and i compile this for android SDK, **Main problem am facing is FaceBook class is not including showing cannot resolve symbol 'Facebook'**

any one can help me how to include android SDK, and with simple program.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Facebook Developer information, e.g. the Login button, found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

This should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

current facebook sdk version add it in the app gradle and synchr

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think facebook class is changed to the new facebook SDK.
You can visit to this link...
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/Facebook/

and you will show the message as 'This class is no longer available in the most recent version of the SDK'.

Delete Facebook class and try to integrate SDK using facebook guideline
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/